# Use vector to make probability table

Tags: r, statistics, probability

In the form of a probability table, I'd like to illustrate a vector of quantiles divisible by 7 and 5, for marginal probability distributions, and 5 given 7, for conditional probability.

Let's assume this is my data:

```
>prob.table(table(x)) # discrete number and its probability
      20       22       23       24       25       26       27       28       29       30       31 
0.000152 0.000625 0.000796 0.001224 0.003138 0.003043 0.004549 0.006444 0.005938 0.009301 0.009456 
      32       33       34       35       36       37       38       39       40       41       42 
0.013448 0.019839 0.018596 0.026613 0.028902 0.027377 0.035156 0.041379 0.041092 0.047733 0.055827 
      43       44       45       46       47       48       49       50       51       52       53 
0.046099 0.051624 0.055131 0.049779 0.056992 0.049801 0.052912 0.031924 0.049114 0.022880 0.042279 
      54       55       56       57       58       59       61       63       65 
0.013946 0.032340 0.003466 0.021240 0.001227 0.011734 0.005115 0.001491 0.000278
```

How can I turn this into a two-way probability table that shows which numbers are divisible by 7 and/or 5 for marginal and conditional probability?

This is what I'd hope the table to look like

```
       Yes      NO  # Probability of numbers divisible by 7
Yes 0.02754 0.02886 
No  0.02656 0.02831 
# Probability of numbers divisible by 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x <- sample(1:100, 100, replace = TRUE)

# %% is the mod operator, which gives the remainder after the division of the left-hand side by the right-hand side. x %% y == 0 therefore returns TRUE if x is divisible by y
db5 <- x %% 5 == 0
db7 <- x %% 7 == 0

table(db5, db7) / length(x)

#        db7
# db5     FALSE TRUE
#   FALSE  0.62 0.13
#   TRUE   0.24 0.01
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Also, how would I get the conditional probability of `db5=="TRUE"` given `db7=="TRUE"`

Comment: `sum(db5 & db7) / sum(db7)`